# Получить арифметические операторы и два числа после него

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Необходимо получить все совпадения по арифметическому оператору `(- + * /)` и двум числам после него(в числах может присутствовать `e-`). К примеру есть строка: 
`+ / + -2 2 -2 / - 3 2 + 1 0 / -18733.675923168783e-7 3512411.820180601` 
Из нее необходимо получить: 
`+ -2 2`  , `- 3 2`, `+ 1 0`, `/ -18733.675923168783e-7 3512411.820180601`

Есть такой код:

```
/[+*-\/] \-?[\d.e-]+ \-?[\d.e-]+/g
```

Но он вытаскивает: 
`+ -2 2`  , `/ - 3`, `+ 1 0`, `/ -18733.675923168783e-7 3512411.820180601`
Как можно это исправить?

Comment: попробуйте так `'[+*-\/] -?[\d]+\.?[\d]*?(?:e-)?[\d]* -?[\d]+\.?[\d]*?(?:e-)?[\d]*'` выглядит страшновато, но для вашего примера работает

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает :)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```js
/[+*\/-]\s+-?\d*\.?\d+(?:e[+-]?\d+)?\s+-?\d*\.?\d+(?:e[+-]?\d+)?/gi
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/1ES28s/1). **Подробности**:

- `[+*\/-]` - один из символов `+`, `*`, `/` или `-`
- `\s+` - один и более пробельных символов
- `-?` - необязательный символ `-`
- `\d*\.?\d+` - ноль и более цифр, необязательная точка `.` и одна и более цифр
- `(?:e[+-]?\d+)?` - необязательная последовательность: `е`, необязательный `+` или `-`, одна и более цифр
- `\s+-?\d*\.?\d+(?:e[+-]?\d+)?` - то же, что и выше.

См. пример работы JavaScript-кода:

```js
const text = '+ / + -2 2 -2 / - 3 2 + 1 0 / -18733.675923168783e-7 3512411.820180601';
const regex = /[+*\/-]\s+-?\d*\.?\d+(?:e[+-]?\d+)?\s+-?\d*\.?\d+(?:e[+-]?\d+)?/gi;
console.log(text.match(regex));
```